# ESLint - Parse error: Unexpected token semicolon

Tags: eslint

I get
 `Parsing error: Unexpected token :`
For semicolon after config variable in the constructor

```js
constructor(config: any) {
  super(config)
}
```

And also for this variable declaration

```js
let userData: any
```

And also for this one after userData

```js
async createNewUser(userData: object) {
}
```

In order to clarify my configuration here are the configuration files.
This is my package.json

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@codeceptjs/configure": "^0.8.0",
    "@codeceptjs/ui": "0.4.6",
    "codeceptjs": "3.3.2",
    "codeceptjs-expectwrapper": "^1.0.2",
    "codeceptjs-resemblehelper": "^1.9.6",
    "expect": "^26.6.2",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "form-data": "^3.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "playwright": "^1.21.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.23.0",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-codeceptjs": "^1.3.0"
  }
```

This is my .eslintrc:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    "codeceptjs",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [ "src/**/*.ts" ]
    }
  ],
  "env": {
    "codeceptjs/codeceptjs": true,
    "es2020": true,
    "node": true
  },

  "rules": {
//    "codeceptjs/no-actor-in-scenario": "warn",
    "codeceptjs/no-skipped-tests": "error"
  }
}
```

Can you please help? I tried looking for the solution but couldn't find anything on this ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest fix may be to extend the default ESLint rules for TypeScript. Add this block to your `.eslintrc`:

```
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
]
```